# Controller Update data got error when connect to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I want to use the stored procedure with MVC but something wrong when I try to update data with id:

> Procedure or function 'StpEmployee' expects parameter '@EmployeeID', which was not supplied

This is my stored procedure:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE StpEmployee  
 (  
     @EmployeeID INT,
     @EmpLastName NVARCHAR(20),
     @EmpFirstName NVARCHAR(50),
     @EmpAge INT,
     @EmpAddress NVARCHAR(255)= NULL,
     @EmpSalary DECIMAL = NULL,
     @EmpEmail NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
     @EmpPhone NVARCHAR(10) = NULL, 
     @TranType nvarchar(20) = ''  
 )  
AS  
BEGIN  
     IF @TranType = 'Insert'  
     BEGIN  
         INSERT INTO Employee(EmpLastName,EmpFirstName,EmpAge,EmpAddress,EmpSalary,EmpEmail,EmpPhone)VALUES(@EmpLastName,@EmpFirstName,@EmpAge,@EmpAddress,@EmpSalary,@EmpEmail,@EmpPhone)  
END  
IF @TranType = 'Select'  
BEGIN  
    SELECT * FROM Employee  
END  
IF @TranType = 'Update'  
BEGIN  
    UPDATE Employee SET EmpLastName=@EmpLastName,EmpFirstName=@EmpFirstName,EmpAge=@EmpAge,EmpAddress=@EmpAddress,EmpSalary=@EmpSalary,EmpEmail=@EmpEmail,EmpPhone=@EmpPhone
    WHERE EmployeeID=@EmployeeID 
END  
ELSE IF @TranType = 'Delete'  
BEGIN  
    DELETE FROM Employee WHERE EmployeeID=@EmployeeID  
END 
ELSE IF @TranType = 'Search'
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE EmpLastName LIKE @EmpLastName OR EmpFirstName LIKE @EmpFirstName 
    OR EmpAddress LIKE @EmpAddress OR EmpEmail LIKE @EmpEmail OR EmpPhone LIKE @EmpPhone
END
```

END

and this my controller:

```
 using (con)
            {
                using (cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {

                    cmd.CommandText = "StpEmployee";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TranType", "Update");
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empID", EmployeeID);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lname);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", fname);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", age);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", add);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salary", salary);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", phone);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        return View("Error", new HandleErrorInfo(ex, "Employee", "Edit"));
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empID", EmployeeID);
```

To this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", EmployeeID);
```

**All** of your other parameters will have the same issue. So change them all.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpLastName", lname);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpFirstName", fname);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpAge", age);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpAddress", add);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpSalary", salary);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpEmail", email);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpPhone", phone);
```

The names of the parameters must match in both the stored procedure, and the code.